# return fields of a structure from a function in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have following structure in C and trying to assign a string into `title` field of `menuButtons` structure. But I getting an error:

`Error C2440 "=": unable to convert from "const char [6]" to "char *"`

```
struct menuButtons {
    int xTopLeft;
    int yTopLeft;
    int xBottomRight;
    int yBottomRight;
    char *title;


} easy, medium, hard;

struct menuButtons getEasyInfo() {
    easy.xTopLeft = 190;
    easy.yTopLeft = 200;
    easy.xBottomRight = 450;
    easy.yBottomRight = 280;
    easy.title = "EASY MODE";   --> error
    return easy;
}
```